# Why does Macrium Reflect Free add another Recovery partition when I restore a system image backup?

Tags: windows-10, backup, hard-drive

I am using Macrium Relect Free to make backups of my computer.

I used it to make a system image backup of Windows 10 on an SSD. To test I booted into the Macrium Rescue media USB key and restored the image to a different HDD. Macrium added another Recovery partition to the end of the HDD. Is it supposed to do that?

I have two disks in my laptop.. Disk 0 is the SSD and Disk 1 is the HDD. I made an image backup of the SSD and restored it to the HDD. Here is a screenshot to illustrate. Why did Macrium add another Recovery partition to the end of Disk 1? Is that just standard practice? Is it better to have it at the end? Can I move or delete it? Which one should I keep?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was... a recovery partition was already on the destination disk. When I went to restore a system image backup to the destination disk I did not **delete existing partitions** on the destination disk.

So Macrium does not add another recovery partition at the end of the disk.